# Angular 6 + firebase hosting no ssr

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I made an app angular 6.0.0 with `ssr` following this guide :

https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

When I build my app `npm run build:ssr` and run `npm run serve:ssr` - **SSR works**. 
When I deploy my app to firebase host, **SSR not working**.

It's firebase foult or mine ? Locally ssr works ( runs with ngExpressEngine ), but in firebase host it won't work.

Comment: I think you need a node.js server to run ssr, but firebase host it's only a static server... but, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for a clue, will check in another server and write if it works.